# Find polygon that contains all linestring records in PostGIS table

Tags: postgis, linestring, polygon

I'm still pretty new to this stuff, so bear with me.  In PostGIS how could I find a polygon that would contain all the linestring records in a given table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know beforehand what your polygon is, you could do:

```
SELECT * from linetable WHERE ST_Intersects(linetable.the_geom,(SELECT the_geom from polytable where id='123'));
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM linetable WHERE ST_Intersects(linetable.the_geom, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,0 1,0 0))');
```

There are many ways to fetch the polygon you want, but the path is to try for ST_Intersects = true

OR do you need the polygon that encloses all linestrings?

If so, you can use ConvexHull:

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html

Comment: The latter.  And actually, ST_Envelope is more up my problems alley.  But your answer pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem Eric. I wasn't sure if ConvexHull or Envelope would do the trick, but I'm glad that it worked.

Comment: And actually, I was wrong about ST_Envelope.  ST_Extent did the trick though.